# help with a simple method

Tags: ruby

Hi I'm trying to solve the exercise from https://github.com/alexch/learn_ruby

I must write a method which should "multiplies two numbers" and "multiplies an array of numbers". I'm fresh to ruby and solved it, with only one method like this:

```
  def multi(*l)
    sum = 1
    l.flatten! if l.is_a? Array
    l.each{|i| sum = sum*i}
    return sum
  end
```

I'm sure there are better ways, so how can I improve this method? to a more ruby like syntax :)

Answer (score 4):

The `if l.is_a? Array` is not necessary because the way `multi` is define, `l` will always be an array.

The pattern

```
result = starting_value
xs.each {|x| result = result op x}
result
```

can be written more succinctly using `xs.inject(starting_value, :op)`.

So you can write your code as:

```
def multi(*l)
    l.flatten.inject(1, :*)
end
```

If you're ok, with calling the method as `multi(*array)` instead of `multi(array)` to multiply an array, you can leave out the flatten, as well.

Comment: `inject()` is a swiss-army knife routine in Ruby and worth exploring. It's not always the fastest way to accomplish something since some more specific code might already exist, but it's very flexible.

Comment: `def multi(*l); l.reduce(:*); end`

Comment: @Lars: That throws an exception if `l` is empty.

Comment: @sepp2k: `[].reduce(:*)` returns nil here. (1.9.2p0)

Comment: @Lars: Ok, my bad. That's still not the result you'd want, though.

Comment: @sepp2k: How do you know what I'd want it to return for an empty array as input? AFAICS, it's not in the spec.

Comment: @Lars: When I said "you", I didn't mean you in particular, I meant "what *one* would want". The product of the empty set/sequence/array is 1. That's the way I learned it in maths class and it's the only way I've ever seen it implemented in any programming language. Having the empty product be anything but 1, will break several laws, like for example that `multi(arr[0...i]) * multi(arr[i..-1])` for any `0 <= i <= arr.size`. Especially if the empty product is nil, in which case multiplying it with anything will throw an exception. I don't think losing two characters (`1,`) is worth that.